# PythonException: 'KeyError: '/Root'' in Pypdf

Tags: pyspark, pypdf

I get this error PythonException: 'KeyError: '/Root'' whenever I try to read multiple pdfs in through my code. My dataframe contains a list of pdf details including content and metadata. If the df contains only one record then the below code works fine, however as soon as I add another row for the next pdf, the code gives the aforementioned error.

```
import pypdf
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col
import io

# define function to read pdf file using pypdf
def read_pdf(filebytes: bytes):
    pdf_reader = pypdf.PdfReader(io.BytesIO(filebytes))
    pages = []
    for page_num in range(len(pdf_reader.pages)):
        page = pdf_reader.pages[page_num]
        text = page.extract_text()
        
        pages.append(text)
    return pages

# create UDF to apply the read_pdf function to each row of the DataFrame
read_pdf_udf = udf(read_pdf, (StringType()))
pdf_text = df.select(read_pdf_udf('content').alias('text'))

display(pdf_text)
```

Can anyone help me make this work for multiple pdfs?

This is running on a spark cluster in Databricks, I tried looking into the function step by step by as this is an UDF can't really go in.